# Using nested cfloop queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion, cfml, cfloop

I have 2 tables. One is for categories, the second is for Questions.

```
 category table: 

 category_id
 category_name

 questions table:

 question_name
 question_id
 category_id
```

How can I loop though all the category names and show the questions grouped under each category name? Using ColdFusion, so I am assume I should use `<CFLOOP>`

The results should look something like this.

**Category1**

- Question 1
- Question 2

**Category2**

- Question 4
- Question 5

Answer (score 11):

If you loop with `cfoutput`, you can group by a specific column, and then have an inner loop for items in that column.

Like this:

```
<cfquery name="Questions">
    SELECT q.question_name , c.category_name

    FROM questions q
    JOIN category c
        ON c.category_id = q.category_id

    ORDER BY c.category_name , q.question_name
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="Questions" groupby="category_name">
    **#category_name#**
    <cfoutput>
        #question_name#
    </cfoutput>
</cfoutput>
```

<del>Annoyingly, this grouping feature hasn't been added to the main `cfloop`, you need to use it via `cfoutput`. :(</del>

**Update**: In ColdFusion 10 and Railo 4, you can now do this with `cfloop` rather than `cfoutput`. Note however that the attribute is **group** not **groupby**:

```
<cfloop query="Questions" group="category_name">
    **#category_name#**
    <cfloop>
        #question_name#
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

**Important:** If this is HTML output, use `HtmlEditFormat(question_name)` to avoid potential HTML injection. Similarly, `JsStringFormat(question_name)` to avoid JS injection, etc.

Again, both CF10/R4 have improved this sitution too, with more consitently named `encodeForX` methods (i.e. `encodeForHtml`, `encodeForJavaScript`, etc)

Comment: How would I structure the loop like your example?

Comment: @jeff, what do u mean? cfoutput already loop over the query for you.

Comment: btw, don't forget to use htmlEditFormat() in between the ##. :)

Comment: Sorry, have it now.  Was confused by the nested cfoutput tags. Thank you very much Peter. Thank Henry as well.

Comment: Yeah, your confusion is exactly why it'd be better using cfloop tags. (If the Advisory Committee was getting anywhere I'd try asking for it to be added to core.)  Henry - good point, must escape output - although no guarantee this is HTML. ;)